# Can't send SMTP Mail PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Well, I developed a generalized project on core PHP and which includes mailing system. A representative of a university registers his university and a mail is sent to my account to investigate whether to give a demo or premium Portal ownership or not. Then the whole process continues. 
I have deployed it almost a year ago and i was working fine. But today i cloned it from repository

https://github.com/TheAkif/alumni-portal

and ran it on localhost and it is not sending email and giving me these errors:

```
    2019-08-01 06:01:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
    2019-08-01 06:01:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
    2019-08-01 06:01:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
    2019-08-01 06:01:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
    2019-08-01 06:01:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
    2019-08-01 06:01:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not 
    accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/? 
    p=BadCredentials f204sm108618451wme.18 - gsmtp
    2019-08-01 06:01:13 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 
    Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials f204sm108618451wme.18 - 
    gsmtp
    SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
    2019-08-01 06:01:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
    2019-08-01 06:01:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection 
    f204sm108618451wme.18 - gsmtp
    SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

mailer.php looks like this.

```
    // Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
    // These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    //Load Composer's autoloader
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
        $mail->Username = 'zyx@gmail.com';                
        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxx';                   
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                        
        $mail->Port = 587;                                
        $mail->setFrom('zyx@gmail.com', 'Portal');
        $mail->addAddress('xyz@gmail.com', 'Something');
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                   
        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    }
```

Comment: Which part of `Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials` was unclear?

Comment: I have `enabled IMAP` and also double checked the password is correct. These two things this link is saying to do!

Comment: When you have tried something, *say so in your question*. IMAP doesn't have anything to do with this. Have you read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)? Google often doesn't like logins from new locations and it can help to log in via a browser and do the captcha unlock procedure described in the guide.